# Sending/receiving data in China using AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

I would like to use AWS DynamoDB/S3/SES/SNS services (Region: Singapore) for my mobile app. The app will be available to users in Singapore/Malaysia/China.

My concern is that will there be any problems for users in China due to China's Firewall?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Not really an answer for this question but I learnt that serving Chinese customer with server outside China is a pain according to this forum post. You might need to think of something else.  https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/58ffuj/if_i_open_an_amazon_china_account_and_host/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight answer of your question is Yes.It will be accessible in China.But not reliably.Due to ***Great Firewall*** things are not easy with china.

**Below information will be helpful in your case:**

1. Account reps can help with a leased line to ap-southeast-1 (cost is manageable but set up time is not fixed). That should help GFW.([Link](https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws/issues/303))
2. Amazon SNS can now deliver messages to users in China through the Baidu Cloud Push

> > Baidu Cloud Push – Delivering push notifications in China on Android is more complex than other parts of the world. With many different app stores and push services, our customers are now realizing that this is a difficult issue to solve and have asked for additional options. In order to allow app developers to address this large and rapidly growing market and to avoid having to customize their code for every app store, Amazon SNS can now deliver messages to users in China through the Baidu Cloud Push, regardless of the app store that they use.
> >
> > Messages can originate in any of the public AWS Regions and will be routed appropriately. You will need to create an account, register as a developer, and obtain the appropriate identifiers (userId and channelId) in order to use this service.

[Full Details](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sns-mobile-push-update-baidu-windows/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What about dynamoDB/S3/SES?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to provide services to users in China, then you need to host your services in China. Having a website in Singapore will NOT provide reliable services to users in China. Also consider that China is broken down into provinces that each have control over their own Internet policies.

I am an Alibaba Cloud MVP for both networking and security. I am also ICP trained and certified (the government regulations regarding websites in China). I have 12 years experience with AWS.

The key to hosting a website (which includes any services providing content / data) in China is an ICP license. This license is very similar to our business license in the US. For the first level, the application process is very easy and quick. The second level is more difficult. Unless you are an enterprise class company you will not be applying for level 3.

Here are the steps to follow if you want to provide a webstite to China.

1) Purchase a domain name with a registrar in China. Use DNS services for China in China.

2) Acquire your website hosting service in China. This is mandatory.

3) Build and publish your website exactly as your users will see it. For a few days, your website will be visible in China but then you will be blocked due to a missing ICP number (see below). This means that you will be duplicating the services that you have outside China with services inside China.

4) File your ICP application listing the exact website and domain name that you are applying for. Your content will be reviewed. You will need to retain the services of a native Chinese speaker as the application process, emails, etc. is in Chinese. The use of Chinese with the government is also mandatory.

5) Even if you plan to process credit cards on your website, do NOT do this at the first stage. Get your ICP license approved first. There are 3 levels, start at the bottom.

6) Once approved, on each web page at the bottom add the ICP license number. Do not skip this step for any web page.

7) If you plan to process credit cards or other financial methods, apply again for the next level ICP license after waiting for a while - wait at least a month.

Note:  There are variations in both business and licensing requirements in various areas in China. Review these items as this will affect where you select the province to host the actual location of your web server. My recommendation is to host in Southeast China, near Hong Kong, unless your user traffic is in the Northeast (Beijing).